# Find the limit of this expression

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried replacing $1-x$ with $1/u$ to get a form that L'Hospital's method could be applicable but I didn't get anything. Can someone give me a hint?

$$
   \lim_{x \to 1} \;\; \tan{\Big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\Big)}(1-x)
$$

Comment: Substitute $y=x+1$ and make a series expansion at $y=0$...

Comment: can we do it only by l'hopital

Comment: hint $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{\cot \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)}$$ then you can apply l'hopital

Answer (score 2):

Let $1-x=t$, then the limit can be written as 
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\tan\left(\frac{\pi (1-t)}{2}\right)t = \lim_{t \to 0}\cot\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)t=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)t}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}t \cdot \frac{2}{\pi}}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)}=\frac{2}{\pi}.$$

I have used $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1$.

Comment: why do you make the pass from the third expression to the fourth?

Comment: To apply the sine limit we should ensure that the angle for the sine matches the argument in the numerator. So I had to multiple and divide by $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $t=1-x$. The limit becomes $$\lim_{t\to 0}\cot({\pi\over 2}t)\times t=\lim_{t\to 0}\cos ({\pi\over 2}t).{t\over \sin ({\pi\over 2}t)}$$